# Generate random date for only weekdays

Tags: php, date, random

I'm trying to generate random date, any day from 10 to 30 days after the current day and the generated day should not be Saturday and Sunday. I search quite a lot but haven't found the solution for this.

Comment: Create a list of all the possible values and choose one at random?  If you are only looking ahead by such a small amount then this is the simplest way to get things done.

Comment: Hi Jeff Foster, because i need to run the code everyday. Everyday creating a list is not very convenient

Comment: Generate date using SQL, C%, PHP, Java, or/and ...?

Comment: Oops, sorry, i was asking about PHP, anyway one friend is coding for me, i will post the solution here when it is done, sine i'm in urgent need for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
repeat
  day <- pickRandomDay(10 ... 30)
until (not satOrSun(day))
return day
```

You won't get too many times round the loop.